# Using properties defined by <context:property-placeholder> in a factory method

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have written a factory bean that creates a cache manager based on the properties that are configured in a application specific properties file.

The concept is that multiple implementations can be chosen, each using other configuration properties.

For example:

- noop cache, without parameters,
- ehcache with #max objects
- memcache with multiple ips and ports configured.

I think it is nice to not specify all cache-application specific parameters in the `application-context.xml`, but read them from the existing properties sources.

My attempt was using a `EnvironementAware` interface to get access to the `Environement`. But it  seems that the property file that is configured using `<context:property-placeholder>` is not contained in the `PropertiesSources`.

example.properties

```
cache.implementation=memcached
cache.memcached.servers=server1:11211,server2:11211
```

application-context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="example.properties"/>
<bean id="cacheManager" class="com.example.CacheManagerFactory"/>
```

In CacheManagerFactory.java

```
public class CacheManagerFactory implements FactoryBean<CacheManager>, EnvironmentAware {

    private Environement env;

    @Override
    public CacheManager getObject() throws Exception {
        String impl = env.getRequiredProperty("cache.implementation"); // this fails
    //Do something based on impl, which requires more properties.
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return CacheManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? I think they improved this in version 3.1 http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Answer (score 3):

In config file like this :

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
  ...
 <property name="email" value="${property1.email}"/>
 <!-- or -->
 <property name="email">
   <value>${property1.email}</value>
 </property>
```

or in code :

```
@Value("${cities}")
private String cities;
```

where the your.properties contains this :

```
cities = my test string 
property1.email = answer@stackvoerflow.com
```

Comment: I don't think you got the point of my question. I would like to be able to access properties that are defined by the `<context:property-placeholder>` within my factory method.

Comment: @HafkensitE is there a reason you can not use the second method I posted

Comment: It is possible that I have a lot of configuration parameters for each cache implementation. And I want to be able to use different configurations with the same compiled classes.
If I understand correctly I would have to specify all parameters/properties in my applicationcontext

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, its relatively simple to multiple properties and property files.

Comment: Thanks for the "in code" part of your answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for - how to reference a property programmatically from within a spring junit integration test.